# How to print the area of a circle in another method

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to print out the answer for the Area of a circle in the myPrint(); method but it keeps calculating zero why?
I did my calculations in the Math(); method that I created. I am very new at coding and would greatly appreciate the help. 
Thanks

```
package Project1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code1 {

    static String myStr;
    static double radius;
    static double answer;
    static double pie;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Name();
        Info();
        Math();
        myPrint();
    }
    public static void Name(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What Is Your Name");
        myStr = input.nextLine();
    }
    public static void Info(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String myStr;

        System.out.println("What is Your Phone Number");
        myStr = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is Your Age");
        myStr = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is Your Postal Code");
        myStr = input.nextLine();

    }
    public static void Math(){
        double radius,answer;
        double pie = 3.14;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the Area of the Circle");
        radius = input.nextDouble();
        answer = pie *(radius * radius);

    }
    public static void myPrint(){
        System.out.print("The answer is:"+ answer);

    }
}
```

Comment: don't mind that there is no package i just for got to copy paste that. same goes for the scanner

Comment: This is what its printing out now

Comment: What Is Your Name
4
What is Your Phone Number
4
What is Your Age
4
What is Your Postal Code
4
What is the Area of the Circle
4
The answer is:0.0

Answer (score 0):

You have the static variable answer, but you declare answer again in Math(), so when you assign answer equal to your calculation, that's not changing the global variable, but it's changing the local variable. When you print answer in myPrint(), the answer will be 0 because it will have been assigned a value of 0 by default.

Comment: One other thing to note, you can use Math.PI instead of declaring your own variable for it. It will be far more accurate!

Comment: I have one more thing to ask is it possible to have my user prompts in my info methods  and put it in the my print as well

Comment: Do you mean you'd just like to print out the values that the user enters?

Comment: yea i want to know how to do that but under the my print option

Comment: if you have some String myStr, then you can simply do System.out.println("this is the input string " + myStr);
Since myStr is just as much a String as "this is the input string"!

Comment: do i put the scanner under that

Comment: well if you want to print the value entered by the user, you would need to do
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter some value: ")
String myStr = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered " + myStr)